# c++ vector compilation error

Tags: c++, vector

Source is very primitive and uses Stanford's lib vector.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vector.h"

void countIntRange(Vector<int>& v, int a, int b);

int main(){
    Vector <int> v;
    v.add(28);
    v.add(1);
    v.add(17);
    v.add(4);
    v.add(41);
    v.add(9);
    v.add(59);
    v.add(8);
    v.add(31);
    v.add(30);
    v.add(25);
    int min = 10;
    int max = 30;
    countIntRange(v, min, max);

    return 0;
}

void countIntRange(Vector<int>& v, int a, int b){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        if (v.get(i) > a && v.get(i) < b){
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count;
}
```

while compiling g++ throws such error:

```
highlander@linux-f62d:~/Documents/CS106b/libs> g++ ex31.cpp
/tmp/ccfH1i0N.o: In function `Vector<int>::get(int) const':
ex31.cpp:(.text._ZNK6VectorIiE3getEi[_ZNK6VectorIiE3getEi]+0x4b): 
    undefined reference to `error(std::string)'
/tmp/ccfH1i0N.o: In function `Vector<int>::insert(int, int)':
ex31.cpp:(.text._ZN6VectorIiE6insertEii[_ZN6VectorIiE6insertEii]+0x6c): 
    undefined reference to `error(std::string)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is error message....
What it doesn't like?

Here goes whole vector.h code https://gist.github.com/HighlanderGe/9023734

Comment: You have to show us the `get` and `insert` function of your `Vector` class

Comment: `undefined reference` is likely a missing library

Comment: You either didn't compile the given code into a library that you can link to via `g++` or you didn't put `vector.h` (and all other dependencies) in your compile command. Just a curious question though, why don't you use `std::vector`?

Comment: I'm newbee, so please explain better how to compile library ?

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve it depends on how you are using the [Stanford cslib library](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/cppdoc/):

- If you compiled it into a library, say `StanfordCSLib`, you need to add `-lStanfordCS` to your `g++` command line
- If you want to use library sources directly, you need to add `StanfordCS/*.cpp` to the list of files that you give `g++`.

The first approach is better, because it avoids multiple recompiles. The second approach may be more expedient if you need to get a single set of sources to work.

Comment: Thank you, but, in case of -lStanfordCS I must install it somehow so that g++ will know what I mean but now I just have directory with files...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i get this working:

1. Create a header file named `vector.h` and copy paste all the file contents in it.
2. Comment out lines for the files `foreach.h` and `strlib.h` in `vector.h`.
3. Create a custom header file and add an include of this file top of `vector.h` file with contents of following:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
>
> void error(std::string msg)
> {
>   std::cout << msg << std::endl;
> }
> ```

4.Compile source file with new header files(`vector.h` and `custom_header.h`)